Can you store the value of the predicted variable (Y) at each fold and then correlate the predicted values with the actual data?
In particular, imagine to have a set of features (X) that I use to predict a continuos variable (Y). Is it possible to use elastic net, in a cross-validation framework, use it to predict the value of Y for each fold, store the predicted Y and then correlate it with the actual Y? Can it be considered a good way to evaluate the performance of the elastci net model? It seems pretty obvious to me that it shouldn't be a robust procedure, because the score used for the evaluation should be averaged for each fold; however I've been arguing with a person who belives it is, and I failed to find any sources that cite this problem.

This approach does make sense to me. Why do you think one should calculate an evaluation score for each fold (and then presumably average these over folds)? Except that correlation is a bit problematic as an error metric because it does not capture bias: $y$ and $y+c$ are perfectly correlated, but $y+c$ is a biased prediction for $y$ if $c\neq 0$.

What do you mean that the score should be averaged for each fold? $//$ I second the criticism of using correlation: $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(11, 21, 31, 41)$ have perfect correlation, yet neither represents perfect predictions of the other.

@StephanKolassa @Dave, thank you for your response.  The belief that the score should be averaged from what I did in the past using MSE. I believed that the MSE should be calculated for the prediction at each fold and then averaged (I honestly thought this was common practice). I also think thats what the cross_validate function of sklearn does. Calculating the MSE of the whole predicted Ys should lead to different results. If both methods are acceptable then I'm sorry for the confusion

Do you mean that you should get that the out-of-sample correlations (or MSEs) across five folds are $0.8$, $0.9$, $0.6$, $0.9$, and $0.8$, for an average correlation (or MSE) value of $0.8?$ What would one do instead?

If all folds are of equal size, then calculating an MSE per fold and averaging these will give you the same result as storing all predictions and averaging their SEs. If the folds differ in size, the two approaches yield different results - but since folds are usually chosen to differ by at most one item, the difference is usually negligible. I don't think it makes an appreciable difference.

@StephanKolassa thanks for the clarification. Would that hold true for correlation as well? At least intuitively, if the fold size is relatively small the correlation may differ greatly between folds. I understand and agree with the critique of using correlation as an error metric, however, assuming it is mandatory to use correlation in this example, which evaluation method would you advise (correlating the stored prediction or evaluate the correlation at each fold)?

No, it does not hold that the average of the correlation is equal to the overall correlation. (Just simulate four pairs of data points and compare the average of the correlations of the first two and the last two to the overall correlation, these will be different almost surely.) I would in this case evaluate the overall correlation, as your colleague suggests. After all, the average of the foldwise correlations depends on how you cut your data into folds, even if predictions and actuals are the same - this does not make a lot of sense, does it?

@StephanKolassa, thanks for the timely answers. I now understand where I was wrong
